# Convert array of strings to array of integers

Tags: j

How do I convert types in J?

For example, how to I convert an array of strings like `"4" "78" "0" "_1"` to an array of numbers like `4 78 0 _1`

Comment: I can't think of any way that you would end up with something like `"4" "78" "0" "_1"`; and that would certainly not be an "array of strings". To convert strings to numbers you can use `".`. To convert integer to string you can use `":`.

Answer (score 1):

*Note that what you call a string is, in fact, a byte list, so a string array is just a byte array of higher dimension.*

There is a J primitive to interpret a byte array as a number, which is *number* (dyadic `".`). It's dyadic because you also have to provide a default value in case a string cannot be interpreted as a number, or if some padding has to be done.

The usage is very simple: `__".'2 -3 4e 5.6 _ .7'` gives `2 _3 __ 5.6 _ 0.7` (see [the documentation](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/quotedot)). As per the note, this generalizes to higher dimension arrays:

```
    __".'2 -3 4e 5.6 _ .7',:'1 7 9 2 4 1'
2 _3 __ 5.6 _ 0.7
1  7  9   2 4   1
```